# Can the qpad queries be recovered if qpad is closed but the port is open?

Tags: console, kdb, qsqlquery

I ran multiple queries but before saving them, the `qpad` crashed. However the `q-port` on which these queries were running (on my windows machine) is still open. I can recover the variables and functions by `\v` and `\f` respectively.

Is there a way to recover all the `q statements` I ran using `qpad`? I forgot to maintain a log file, hence I am trying to find a way to recover queries using `q-port`.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there's no way to retrieve your old queries for the reasons Davis.Leong said. But if you can't/don't want to create a table on your server to save them, you can also check the log queries box in QPad settings:

Q > Settings > Editor > Log queries to "queries_date.log"

Now when you run queries, they will be written to this log file in the same directory as QPad.exe, along with the server and timestamp, like this:

```
/ 02/26/19 09:54:52 on `:localhost:1234:: from QPad1*
  show `logthis
/ 02/26/19 10:03:03 on `:localhost:1234:: from QPad1*
  a:10
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to retrieve your command history. Others has already mentioned why so I will not go into that. You can easily maintain a log file in the future however:

When you start your server, adding the `-l` flag will allow you to define a path to a log file. Any commands sent to the server from the client will now be logged. For example

```
q ../log/logtest -l -p 5555
t:([]date:`date$();sym:`sym$();price:`float$())
```

will start a q process listening on 5555, logging any messages that cause the server to update. So if I open a handle to 5555 in another q session `` h:hopen `::5555 ``
and 
update table `t`

```
q)h"insert[`t](2000.01.01;`appl;102.3)"
,0
```

the server will have updated `t` like so

```
q)t
date       sym  price
---------------------
2000.01.01 appl 102.3
```

There will be a log file created which will show any commands sent to the server. NOTE however it will only log those commands that change the state of the server's data.

This log file can be reloaded in the event of a server crash using the same command as before.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. qpad is the GUI that interact with the q process. The reason why you can retrieve the variable and function is because the process did not die. For the query, in default q will not save that, unless when you customize your `.z.pg` to upsert a record in a queryHistory table.

e.g.

```
q).z.pg:{[x]`queryHistory insert ([]queryTime:.z.P;query:enlist x)}
q)queryHistory:([]queryTime:`timestamp$();query:())
q)10+10
20
q)testTab:([]sym:10?`1;val:10?100)
q)queryHistory
queryTime query
---------------
```

queryHistory is not append with record as this is being done in q process itself, if you do it in your qpad:

```
10+10
testTab:([]sym:10?`1;val:10?100)
```

you can see there will be record append, so even your GUI is crashed, you can trace the query

```
q)queryHistory
queryTime                     query
-------------------------------------
2019.02.26D17:32:38.471063000 "10+10"
q)queryHistory
queryTime                     query
----------------------------------------------------------------
2019.02.26D17:32:38.471063000 "10+10"
2019.02.26D17:32:52.790863000 "testTab:([]sym:10?`1;val:10?100)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got to know recently, there is a backup of your q scripts at "c/users//Appdata/local" and are autosaved every 5-6 mins.These are temporary files which are deleted when you save the script. However if your qPad crashed, you can find your files here :)